# merge several strings with a separator in one variable, and seperate them once the variable is called

Tags: php

On my website I need to store several urls on my database.
Rather than storing each of them in a different row I chose to put them all in a single row (since when I call them, I need them all anyways).

To do that I store the urls in a single string separated by `||` like this :

> http://url1.com/dhsg.php**||**http://url2.com/jjipg.php**||**http://url3.com/dbhm.php**||**http://url4.com/dheresg.php**||**...

My question is, once I get this string back in a variable, how can I get back each of theses links in order to put them inside individual span ? 
Like :

```
<span>http://url1.com/...</span>  
<span>http://url2.com/...</span>  
<span>http://url3.com/...</span>  
<span>http://url4.com/...</span>
```

Comment: `explode`/`implode`

Comment: I downvoted your question because simply googling separate string php will return loads of results using explode... You didn't even research before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you search is the function explode.

```
<?php
$yourString = 'http://url1.com/dhsg.php||http://url2.com/jjipg.php||http://url3.com/dbhm.php||http://url4.com/dheresg.php';

$arrayWithURLs = explode('||', $yourString);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($arrWithURLs, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>
```

The last echo gives you the result in readable form.

Comment: Aaah thank you ! I was unable to find the correct the way to do this with php and assumed there was no native function to do so, I'm going to try this out right away, thanks for your help !

Comment: your welcome :-) Please dont forget to flag the answer as finished-answer. Br